# script to check cpu utilization in linux

Tags: shell-script, cpu

I want a bash script that show the CPU consumption every minute and save it in a file.

The output would be like this:

```
11/09/2015 10:00: CPU: 60%
11/09/2015 10:01: CPU: 72%
11/09/2015 10:02: CPU: 32%
```

And so on... Can somebody help me ?

I can do it with # sar >> Result.txt but it shows the result every 15 minutes instead of every minute. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Please contact Stack Exchange to get your account back. http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Put this into a bash script somewhere on your system (/opt for example):

```
#!/bin/bash

CPU_USAGE=$(top -b -n2 -p 1 | fgrep "Cpu(s)" | tail -1 | awk -F'id,' -v prefix="$prefix" '{ split($1, vs, ","); v=vs[length(vs)]; sub("%", "", v); printf "%s%.1f%%\n", prefix, 100 - v }')

DATE=$(date "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:")

CPU_USAGE="$DATE CPU: $CPU_USAGE"

echo $CPU_USAGE >> /opt/cpu_usage.out
```

Then create a file called cpu_usage under /etc/cron.d/ with the following in:

```
*/1 * * * * root /opt/your_script.sh
```

This should execute the script once per minute, and output the CPU usage in a percentage format on a new line within the specified file.

Comment: I've amended this to include the date and time stamp in the format you requested.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I tried it and it seems like I need your help once more. I get this output when I executed it.

awk: syntax error near line 1
awk: bailing out near line 1

Comment: No problem. Can I ask which operating system you're using? Exact distribution and version would be very useful - the above method has been known to work with Debian and Redhat derivatives quite well.

Comment: SunOS psac02 5.8 Generic_117350-38 sun4u sparc SUNW,Sun-Fire-V210

I put uname -a, you need sth more?

Comment: Hi danman, my apologies. From your first post I wasn't able to confirm the operating system in use, so posted a solution known to work on the most commonly used ones. I'll provide you with a solution for Solaris within the day if that's okay, as I've got another method in mind for extracting the percentage - but cannot confirm without testing it within my lab this evening.

Comment: It would be perfect! I owe you big time! thanks again :) I'm a new girl into this whole thing..

Comment: Not a problem - we all start somewhere. :-)

If there's anything else I can assist you with just let me know. I should be online tonight, so if you hit any more boundaries we can work through it on chat (that's if it allows me to use chat with you on this site, as your reputation is fairly low).

Comment: @danman I deleted your answer since it was not actually answering. Also, you really, really, don't want to be posting your email address on random websites.

Comment: haha okay, but it was a "trash" account so it didn't matter. Could you test it finally @Hugh-Jersey?

Comment: Ah yes, will look at it soon. Wasn't sure what was happening after the mix up with the account above!

Comment: Finally I did it like this even though it's not exactly as I wanted but close enough.

    sar -u 60 1439 >> myfile.dat &



and I execute it every day at 00:00. So I can keep record of what happens every minute of everyday :)

Comment: Ah excellent. That's good then. Most of the above shell commands/syntax are common place in the popular shells. I just needed to test the command to extract the percentage, which because Solaris is a paid for operating system, wasn't going to be as easy as I had hoped. I'm glad it's all working now though!

Comment: @Hugh-Jersey Thanks for everything anyway! I discover that I hate Solaris..

Comment: is there a quick way to get the opposite value of CPU_USAGE? I mean the completion to 100% (without need to do subtraction action)

Answer (score -2):

```
*/1 * * * * prstat -Z|head -18|tail -1|awk '{print$7}'>filename.txt
```