# Timer in script to check cpu utilization in Linux

Tags: shell-script

I'm looking for a statement to check if CPU is above 90% for 10 minutes, if the cpu does not go below 90% for more than 10 minutes, then alert

My script so far:

```
cpu_used = "90"
```

Taken from [Hugh's script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/228981/script-to-check-cpu-utilization-in-linux)

```
cpu=`top -b -n2 -p 1 | fgrep "Cpu(s)" | tail -1 | awk -F'id,' -v prefix="$prefix" '{ split($1, vs, ","); v=vs[length(vs)]; sub("%", "", v); printf "%s%.1f%%\n", prefix, 100 - v }'`
```

example

```
    if [ $cpu -ge $cpu_used ] ; then
        echo $cpu
    fi
```

how to add 10 minutes to above if statement to check if cpu is above 90% for more than 10 minutes before sending the alert? Thank you in advance

Comment: You cannot tell anything about what CPU load was in between your checks. It can vary in much shorter intervals.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to achieve this is to record the cpu utilization over a 10 minute interval.

Here is how to check if your CPU was over 90% utilization for over a 10 minutes.

```
#!/bin/bash

starttime=$(date +%s)
cpu_used=90
retval="Over 90% for 10 min"
while [ $(($(date +%s) - $starttime)) -le 600 ]
do

cpu=`top -b -n2 -p 1 | fgrep "Cpu(s)" | tail -1 | awk -F'id,' -v prefix="$prefix" '{ split($1, vs, ","); v=vs[length(vs)]; sub("%", "", v); printf "%s%.1f%%\n", prefix, 100 - v }'`
cpu=${cpu::-1}
cpu=${cpu%.*}

# If at any time the current cpu utilization is below the threshold, exit.
if [ $cpu -le $cpu_used ] ; then
        retval="Not over 90% for 10 min"
        break
fi

# Longer you sleep, less resource intensive. However, longer sleep decreases the accuracy.
sleep 1
done

echo $retval
```